# Swift Optional type: how .None == nil works

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm trying to understand how does it work:

```
  1> func returnNone() -> String? { return .None }
  2> returnNone() == nil
$R0: Bool = true
  3> returnNone() == .None
$R1: Bool = true
```

Why `.None` is equal `nil`.

I don't see anything about it in enum definition:

```
public enum Optional<Wrapped> : _Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible {
    case None
    case Some(Wrapped)
    /// Construct a `nil` instance.
    public init()
    /// Construct a non-`nil` instance that stores `some`.
    public init(_ some: Wrapped)
    /// If `self == nil`, returns `nil`.  Otherwise, returns `f(self!)`.
    @warn_unused_result
    @rethrows public func map<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?
    /// Returns `nil` if `self` is nil, `f(self!)` otherwise.
    @warn_unused_result
    @rethrows public func flatMap<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U?) rethrows -> U?
    /// Create an instance initialized with `nil`.
    public init(nilLiteral: ())
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`enum Optional` conforms to the `NilLiteralConvertible` protocol,
which means that it can be initialized with the "nil" literal.
The result is `Optional<T>.None` where the type placeholder `T`
must be inferred from the context.

As an example,

```
let n = nil // type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

does not compile, but

```
let n : Int? = nil
```

does, and the result is `Optional<Int>.None`.

Now optionals can in general not be compared if the underlying
type is not `Equatable`:

```
struct ABC { }

let a1 : ABC? = ABC()
let a2 : ABC? = ABC()

if a1 == a2 { } // binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'ABC?' operands
```

and even this does not compile:

```
if a1 == Optional<ABC>.None { } // binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'ABC?' operands
```

But this compiles:

```
if a1 == nil { }
```

It uses the operator

```
public func ==<T>(lhs: T?, rhs: _OptionalNilComparisonType) -> Bool
```

where `_OptionalNilComparisonType` is not documented officially.
In https://github.com/andelf/Defines-Swift/blob/master/Swift.swift the
definition can be found as (found by @rintaro and @Arsen, see comments):

```
struct _OptionalNilComparisonType : NilLiteralConvertible {
  init(nilLiteral: ())
}
```

This allows the comparison of any optional type with "nil", regardless of whether the underlying type is `Equatable` or not.

In short – in the context of `Optional` – `nil` can be thought of as a shortcut to `.None`, but the concrete type must be inferred from the context. There is a dedicated  `==` operator for comparison with "nil".

Comment: @Cosyn: If you define your own `enum Op<Wrapped>` then you would also have to define the `==` operator for that type. But you are right, the last sentence was misleading.

Comment: @MartinR @Cosyn so what. The answer is somewhere apple defines `==` method for comparison Optional types?

Comment: @Arsen, there is one: public func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool

Comment: @Arsen: Actually there is an operator `public func ==<T>(lhs: _OptionalNilComparisonType, rhs: T?) -> Bool`. The `_OptionalNilComparisonType` is not documented, but this seems to allow the comparison of any optional type with "nil", regardless of whether the underlying type is Equatable or not.

Comment: @MartinR it looks like an answer. Can you update your own answer. I think it can be interesting for people. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, `_OptionalNilComparisonType` is not a `protocol` but a `struct` that just implements `init(nilLiteral: ())` initializer.

Comment: @rintaro: Thanks! I could not find the definition.

Comment: `struct _OptionalNilComparisonType : NilLiteralConvertible {
  init(nilLiteral: ())
}`

Comment: I just have found this link https://github.com/andelf/Defines-Swift/blob/master/Swift.swift it is not an official docs