# How to compare to optional arrays?

Tags: swift, syntax

I'd like a function to compare [String]? with [String]? where either, both or neither are nil. If both are `nil` then the function returns `true`

Is there notation where I can avoid checking a value is equal to nil?

This:

```
func compare_colours(a1:[String]?, a2:[String]?) -> Bool {
    return a1 == a2
}
```

isn't valid in Swift because I'd need to add `!` first:

```
return a1! == a2!
```

Comment: If both inputs are nil then what's the expected return value?

Comment: @martin-r I can see that this Q is very similar to yours. Mine asks for working code and yours why one solution doesn't work. Could this Q be a logical follow-on to yours?

Comment: But the answer to the "duplicate" contains working code.

Comment: But the question is different to this one. I don't mind if you delete this question - I just think I've asked a different question. The code in an answer to your question is noted as causing "infinite recursion". Were you referring to code in your question rather than in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
if let a1Unwrapped = a1{
    if let a2Unwrapped = a2{
         return a1Unwrapped == a2Unwrapped
    }
}
if (a1 == nil && a2 == nil){
    return true
}
return false
```

Comment: wrong result when both `a1` and `a2` are `nil` (should be `true`)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [`guard`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID525) over `if` statements so I can avoid the [pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)):

```
func compare_colours(a1:[String]?, a2:[String]?) -> Bool {
  if a1 == nil && a2 == nil      { return true  }
  guard let unwrapped1 = a1 else { return false }
  guard let unwrapped2 = a2 else { return false }
  return unwrapped1 == unwrapped2
}
```

You don't need to check for nil. Instead you can check to see if the Optional enum is .None:

```
switch (a1, a2) {
case (.None, .None): print("Both unset Optional")
}
```

Either way you have to do the same basic thing, check for nil/.None. For more details on how this works you can read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33209762/887210

Comment: wrong result when both `a1` and `a2` are `nil` (should be `true`)

Comment: True, although it really isn't specified what the expected result should be if they are both nil.

Comment: This is a working solution wrt code. But you've not answered my sub-question: "Is there notation where I can avoid checking a value is equal to nil?" with a "no, there is not" :) - add that and I can tick.

Answer (score -1):

Or just use the optional as an empty and you can match all scenarios.

```
func compare_colours(a1:[String]?, a2:[String]?) -> Bool {
    return a1 ?? [""] == a2 ?? [""]
}
```

Comment: With your approach `[""] == nil`

Comment: As it should be. He is checking to see if an array of colors is equal to another set. If one is empty and the other nil then they are in this sense, equal. Simplicity.